# Was the Dragon Half manga ever translated?

Tags: dragon-half

I remember with fondness watching the 2 episode anime Dragon Half, which I'm lead to believe is based on a long running manga which parodies tropes in manga and anime.

Was the manga every translated to English, or were there ever any more episodes made of the anime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manga had not previously been licensed for English release, but it was fully translated by fans years ago. Now, in 2017, Seven Seas Entertainment has licensed the manga and will release all 7 volumes in a 3-volume omnibus edition, with the first one coming out this December.

Answer (score 3):

The seven-volume Dragon Half manga was never licensed or officially localized in English. The OVA only consisted of two episodes (previously by [ADV Films](http://www.mania.com/dragon-half_article_74723.html), now currently by [DiscoTek Media](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-11-10/discotek-adds-dna2-1st-lupin-iii-tv-special-dragon-half-ova-fatal-fury-specials)). Those two episodes persist as the only animated versions of the series.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Based on Krazer's answer, the series has never been officially translated, but unofficially it has been scanslated online and can be read at many manga reading sites. So, yes and no, it has been and has not been translated. A group of volunteers, who earn no profit, did work on it, but professional manga producers did not work on it for distribution.